# How to ignore duplicate Primary Key in SQL?

Tags: sql, duplicates, primary-key

I have an excel sheet with several values which I imported into SQL (book1$) and I want to transfer the values into ProcessList. Several rows have the same primary keys which is the ProcessID because the rows contain original and modified values, both of which I want to keep. How do I make SQL ignore the duplicate primary keys?

I tried the IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON but for rows with duplicated primary key, only 1 the latest row shows up.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ProcessList
(
    Edited              varchar(1),
    ProcessId           int             NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON),
    Name                varchar(30)     NOT NULL,
    Amount              smallmoney      NOT NULL,
    CreationDate        datetime        NOT NULL,
    ModificationDate    datetime
)

INSERT INTO ProcessList SELECT Edited, ProcessId, Name, Amount, CreationDate, ModificationDate FROM Book1$
SELECT * FROM ProcessList
```

Also, if I have a row and I update the values of that row, is there any way to keep the original values of the row and insert a clone of that row below, with the updated values and creation/modification date updated automatically?

Comment: I'd recommend loading the data into a scratch table with no constraints. Then do further processing to load the data into a table with a primary key and other constraints. Handle the duplicates as part of this process.

Comment: How many times can a process be edited? As a varchar(1) I'm guessing possibly just once? In which case perhaps your primary key is actually the combination of Edited and ProcessId. E.g. `PRIMARY KEY (Edited, ProcessId)` rather than defining the primary key on the single column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I make SQL ignore the duplicate primary keys?

Under no circumstances can a transaction be committed that results in a table containing two distinct rows with the same primary key.  That is fundamental to the nature of a primary key.  SQL Server's `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option does not change that -- it merely affects how SQL Server *handles* the problem.  (With the option turned on it silently refuses to insert rows having the same primary key as any existing row; otherwise, such an insertion attempt causes an error.)

You can address the situation either by dropping the primary key constraint or by adding one or more columns to the primary key to yield a composite key whose *collective* value is not duplicated.  I don't see any good candidate columns for an expanded PK among those you described, though.  If you drop the PK then it might make sense to add a synthetic, autogenerated PK column.

> Also, if I have a row and I update the values of that row, is there any way to keep the original values of the row and insert a clone of that row below, with the updated values and creation/modification date updated automatically?

If you want to ensure that this happens automatically, however a row happens to be updated, then look into triggers.  If you want a way to automate it, but you're willing to make the user ask for the behavior, then consider a stored procedure.

Comment: Creating a composite PK is a brilliant idea to solve this issue if you can't drop your PK (if used as a FK constraint for ex.). Thx @John!

Answer (score 0):

try this

`INSERT IGNORE INTO ProcessList SELECT Edited, ProcessId, Name, Amount, CreationDate, ModificationDate FROM Book1$
SELECT * FROM ProcessList`

Answer (score -1):

You drop the constraint.  Something like this:

```
alter table dbo.ProcessList drop constraint PK_ProcessId;
```

You need to know the constraint name.

In other words, you can't ignore a primary key.  It is defined as unique and not-null.  If you want the table to have duplicates, then that is not the primary key.